# How to convert WAV audio file to FLAC format in javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, audio, flac, recorder

I am recording audio in wav format using recorder.js https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs but google's speech API accept only FLAC format of audio.  Could anyone guide me either to a FLAC recorder or how to convert the recorded wav file to a FLAC file on client side or server side(linux server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAV files can simply converted to FLAC via `ffmpeg` with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav output.flac
```

You can find more documents about `ffmpeg` in the [official site](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), Also there is a `php` wrapper for the `ffmpeg` binary [on github](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg).

Comment: problem solved using SOX on server :)